# Proving that if $r$ is rational, then $\frac27(3r+5)-9$ is also rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I'm trying to write a proof but I'm getting stuck. I have to prove that

> For all real numbers $r$, if $r$ is rational, then $\frac27(3r+5)-9$ is also rational.

I let $r = a/b$ by definition of rational. Then I substituted $r$ for $a/b$. After doing some algebra, I got down to $$\frac27\cdot\frac{3a+5b}{b}-9$$ but I'm not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here is show that $(2/7)(3r+5)-9$ can be written in the form $A/B$, where $A$ and $B$ are integers. To do this, keep going with what you started:

$${2\over7}\left({3a\over b}+5\right)-9={2\over7}\cdot{3a+5b\over b}-9={6a+10b\over7b}-9={6a+10b-63b\over7b}={6a-53b\over7b}$$

and now note that this is of the form $A/B$ where $A=6a-53b$ and $B=7b$ are integers.

Comment: Just to remind, the denominator should be non-zero and this should be **included** in the proof.

Comment: @ultralegend5385, good point. To be more fully rigorous, the proof should start with the requirement $b\not=0$ in writing $r=a/b$, and end with the observation that $b\not=0$ implies $7b\not=0$ (as I just now see you put it in your answer).

Comment: Of course, I meant that. It wouldn't make sense otherwise! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Continue:
$$\underbrace {\frac {6a+10b}{7b}}_m-9$$
Here, $m$ is a rational as $a $ and $b $ are integers and multiplication and addition are closed under integers. Further, $b\neq0$ implies $7b\neq0$. So, $m$ is rational.

Now, combine the fact that difference of two rationals is a rational.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)